# How can I purchase additional quota in the YouTube Data API v3?

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-data-api, limit, quota

How can I purchase additional quota in the YouTube Data API v3? I couldn't find the option to buy more quota or the associated prices. I have multiple projects, but using multiple API keys resulted in the suspension of my projects. Can someone please help me with this?

I tried to create more than one project to increase my quota, but it resulted in the suspension of my projects.

Comment: You can't buy quota, but you can [request quota](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).